# Excel VBA - Find minimum of list of values?

Tags: vba, excel

For a list like:

```
Column1     Column2     Column3    
DataA       1           1234    
DataA       2           4678    
DataA       3           8910    
DataB       2           1112    
DataB       4           1314    
DataB       9           1516
```

How do I get a list like this:

```
Column4    Column5      Column6    
DataA      1            1234    
DataB      2            1112
```

The key is to only return the minimum value in column2 and its corresponding column3 value.

Comment: This is one of those Excel examples where I really would want to throw the data into Access and run a query. Using `GroupBy` and the `Min` function would get you exactly what you're looking for. Something like: `SELECT Column1, Column2, Min(Column3) As Column3 FROM Table GROUP BY Column1`.  Granted, writing the code for this is a great excercise, but sometimes using a tool like Access can be very helpful for something like this.

Comment: There is no need for Access, Excel is quite happy with ADO.

Comment: This would have been easy in Access - but the tool is Excel...  
The ADO sample looks interesting.

Comment: It's still pretty easy in Excel. Sort by the Key (column A) and the the value (column c). Then in D2 put the value of C2. Finally in D3 put this formula: =IF(A3<>A2,C3,D2) and copy down. Copy/Paste Special Values and call it a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood your Question First. Here is a working code that ended up more complex than I wanted it to be :D

```
Option Explicit

Private Function inCollection(ByRef myCollection As Collection, ByRef value As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    inCollection = False

    For i = 1 To myCollection.Count
        If (myCollection(i) = value) Then
            inCollection = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Sub listMinimums()

    Dim source As Range
    Dim target As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim datas As New Collection
    Dim minRows As New Collection

    Set source = Range("A2:C5")
    Set target = Range("D2")
    target.value = source.value

    For Each row In source.Rows
        With row.Cells(1, 1)
            If (inCollection(datas, .value) = False) Then
                datas.Add .value
                minRows.Add row.row, .value
            End If
            If (Me.Cells(minRows(.value), 2) > row.Cells(1, 2)) Then
                minRows.Remove (.value)
                minRows.Add row.row, .value
            End If
        End With
    Next row

    'output'
    For i = 1 To minRows.Count
        target(i, 1) = Me.Cells(minRows(i), 1)
        target(i, 2) = Me.Cells(minRows(i), 2)
        target(i, 3) = Me.Cells(minRows(i), 3)
    Next i

    Set datas = Nothing
    Set minRows = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note: You might want to replace `Me` with the name of your sheet.

Answer (score 1):

An example using ADO.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim i As Integer

''http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246335

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT Column1, Min(Column3) As MinCol3 FROM [Sheet8$] GROUP BY Column1"

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

For i = 0 To rs.fields.Count - 1
    Sheets("Sheet7").Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.fields(i).Name
Next

Worksheets("Sheet7").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: This might seem like a fun idea, but it is very slow

Comment: I get less than a second for 48,000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public Sub MinList()
    Const clColKey_c As Long = 1&
    Const clColVal_c As Long = 3&
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet, objDict As Object
    Dim lRow As Long, dVal As Double, sKey As String
    Dim lRowFrst As Long, lRowLast As Long, lColOut As Long
    Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet
    Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lRowFrst = ws.UsedRange.Row
    lRowLast = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lColOut = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1&
    For lRow = lRowFrst To lRowLast
        dVal = Val(ws.Cells(lRow, clColVal_c).Value)
        sKey = ws.Cells(lRow, clColKey_c).Value
        If objDict.Exists(sKey) Then
            If dVal > objDict.Item(sKey) Then objDict.Item(sKey) = dVal
        Else
            objDict.Add sKey, dVal
        End If
    Next
    For lRow = lRowFrst To lRowLast
        ws.Cells(lRow, lColOut).Value = objDict.Item(ws.Cells(lRow, clColKey_c).Value)
    Next
    ws.Cells(1&, lColOut).Value = "Min"
End Sub
```