# Excel: Find the minimal value in a column

Tags: excel

An Excel table consists of two columns (e.g., A1:B5):

```
0 10
1 20
3 30
2 20
1 59
```

I need to get the minimal value in column B for which the corresponding value in column A is greater than zero. In the above example it should be 20.

I tried using various combinations of INDEX(), MIN(), IF(), ROW(), array formulas, etc. - but I just can't figure out how to do it. :-( Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grsm almost had it

if you enter the following formula in C1 as an array (Ctrl+Shift+End)

```
=MIN(IF(A1:A5>0,B1:B5))
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Nice one.. I know there was a hotkey but I just couldn't remember

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make an extra column..

```
A     B     C     D
0     10    false 20
1     20    20
3     30    30
2     40    40
1     50    50
```

column C : =IF(A1>0;B1)

cell D1: =MIN(C1:C5)

Comment: It ought to be doable in a single step, using an array formula... I just can't figure out how... :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in 2 stages

- First use the MIN function to find the minimum
- Then take that answer and use the LOOKUP function to select the row and column that you need.

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? MIN will return the minimal value in column B, regardless of the contents of column A - which is not what I need. And what to use LOOKUP for? I don't need to know the address of the cell that contains the value that interests me; I need only the value itself.

It ought to be doable with some array formula using MIN and IF...

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Minimum And Maximum Values In A Range" example in http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/excelF.htm  (you can download the same as well from the same section)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

This is not identical, but very similar: [Excel VBA - Find minimum of list of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876506/excel-vba-find-minimum-of-list-of-values)